# Boilerplate's and Compass's CSS resets are duplicates or should i keep them both?

Tags: css, compass-sass, html5boilerplate, css-reset

I'm using Boilerplate and Compass on the same project.
Boilerplate have normalizer.css and main.css. and Comapass have screen/print/ie.css.

Is it a good idea to have both the css resets of both libraries or are they just duplicates?
(Compass's files will be linked after Boilerplate's files).

Comment: it will be better don't mix normalize and reset. I think you should use only normalize, because compass styles and mixins will work fine with normalize as well as reset. <br>

Comment: You should use the Boilerplate stylesheets and remove the Compass ones or rename them so they're more semantic to you.  As I am aware, the Compass stylesheets are empty at any rate.